# SQL FOR XML PATH: attributes not staying in the node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 '01' AS '@language', 'a description' as 'data()' FROM @tmpData AS  FOR XML PATH('description'),ROOT('course'),TYPE),  
(SELECT TOP 1 '2016-CRS' AS '@code' FROM @tmpData as t FOR XML PATH('course'),TYPE),
```

This shows:

```
<course>
        <description language="01">a description</description>
</course>
<course code="2016-CRS" />
```

But what I really need is:

```
<course code="2016-CRS">
        <description language="01">a description</description>
</course>
```

I know it is simple but I cannot achieve it. Thanks for any insights!

Comment: What is `@tmpData`? You do not use any value from a table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not all clear, as you are using a data source `FROM @tmpData` without using it at all, but this would return the result you seem to need:

```
SELECT '2016-CRS' AS [@code] 
      ,'01' AS [description/@language]
      ,'a description' as [description]
FOR XML PATH('course')
```

The result

```
<course code="2016-CRS">
  <description language="01">a description</description>
</course>
```

Comment: Thanks but your code does not close the description tag :(

Comment: @MiguelMas Why do you think so? Creating XML with `FOR XML` will ever result in valid XML...

Comment: @MiguelMas Ah, never mind... As you obviously like this answer (thx for the acceptance!) it would be nice to - additionally - upvote it. Thx